# Дочерний интерфейс: подъинтерфейс, подинтерфейс, или подынтерфейс?

Tags: правописание

В программировании (как наверняка многие здесь знают) есть понятие "класс" и "дочерний класс", но более логично называть последнее "подклассом".

И по мимо этого есть понятие интерфейс. До сих пор я его его дочерний вариант писал только по-английски как subinterface. А тут нужно написать по-русски и я завис.

Варианты:

1. Подинтерфейс
2. Подъинтерфейс
3. Подынтерфейс

Все выглядят как-то неправильно.

Comment: По правилам русского языка, конечно, правильный вариант через «ы». Но я бы в принципе не использовал подобную невразумительную терминологию кроме как в контексте Java, где она утверждена официально.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy И еще в C#.

Comment: @Dmitry, не нашёл подобного термина в спецификации C#.

Comment: В логике используется какраз подкласс, так что я стараюсь использовать такие понятия. И да, речь сейчас шла именно о Java.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy Раздел 1.9 в любой версии. Вот [спецификация](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) версии 5.0.

Comment: @Dmitry, ещё раз открыл и не вижу такого термина.

Comment: Может, "субинтерфейс"?

Comment: @user4419802 В соотвтетствии с ответом Quassnoi тогда уже субынтерфейс.

Comment: @Volodya Вот как раз после приставки "суб-" (в отличие от "под-") пишется "и", а не "ы". Такой уж он, русский язык ;-)

Comment: @user4419802 Тогда я точно не буду его субинтерфейсом называть. А то вообще запутаюсь. Если сделаете ваш последний комментарий ответом, будет вам от меня положительная карма.

Comment: Оно, конечно, верно, но страшно. А чем субинтерфейс плох?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Приставки, оканчивающиеся на согласную, для целей правописания можно разделить на "исконно русские" и "заимствованные".

После "русских" приставок, таких как *пред-*, *под-* и пр. пишется буква *ы*, например *предыстория*. Но после "заимствованных", к примеру, *суб-*, *супер-* и пр. нужно писать *и*, например, *суперинтендант*.

Исключениями являются приставки *сверх-* и *меж-* (например, *сверхискренний*, *межинститутский*), а также глагол *взимать* (ср. *взыграть*, *взыскать* и т.п.).

Таким образом, правильно будет **субинтерфейс** или **подынтерфейс**, но никак иначе.

Answer (score 8):

It's *подынтерфейс*, similar to *подынтервал* and *подынтегральный*.

Rosenthal, 33:

> После приставок, оканчивающихся на согласную, вместо *и* пишется *ы* в соответствии с произношением, например: *играть – подыграть, разыграть, сыграть; искать – отыскать, подыскать, разыскать: идейный – безыдейный; индукционный – безындукционный; интегральный – подынтегральный; исторический – предысторический; июльский – предыюльский.*

Note that this rule is only valid for Slavic prefixes except *сверх-* and *меж-*: *суперигра*, *сверхидея*, *межинтервальный*.